# MDX query is SLOWER with warm cache

Tags: performance, ssas, mdx

I have a `MDX` query that executes faster on cold cache than warm cache.

If I ran the same `MDX` query after restarting `SSAS` it takes 14 seconds. All subsequent runs of the same statement then take 50 seconds.

There is no load on the server, and al lot of RAM available and default `SSAS` memory settings.

I am out of ideas as to why this would be the case?

**UPDATE**

MDX traced statement from SSRS Report:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[Total GP %]
     ,[Measures].[Trading GP %]
     ,[Measures].[Closing Stock Value]
     ,[Measures].[Opening Stock Value]
     ,[Measures].[Trading GP]
     ,[Measures].[Total GP]
     ,[Measures].[Purchases Value]
     ,[Measures].[Shortage Value]
     ,[Measures].[Adjustments Value]
     ,[Measures].[Wastage Value]
     ,[Measures].[Sales Value]
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
        [Item].[Item Code].[Item Code].ALLMEMBERS
      * 
        [Item].[Item Description].[Item Description].ALLMEMBERS
    }
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    MEMBER_CAPTION
   ,MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME
   ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    Filter
    (
      [Item].[Item Name].[Item Name].ALLMEMBERS
     ,
        Instr
        (
          [Item].[Item Name].CurrentMember.Properties('Member_Caption'),@ItemItemName
        )
      > 0
    ) ON COLUMNS
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      StrToSet
      (@ItemGroupDescription2
       ,CONSTRAINED
      ) ON COLUMNS
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT 
        StrToSet
        (@ItemGroupDescription
         ,CONSTRAINED
        ) ON COLUMNS
      FROM 
      (
        SELECT 
          StrToSet
          (@BranchBranchName
           ,CONSTRAINED
          ) ON COLUMNS
        FROM 
        (
          SELECT 
            StrToSet
            (@BranchStoreCategory
             ,CONSTRAINED
            ) ON COLUMNS
          FROM 
          (
            SELECT 
              StrToSet
              (@BranchRegion
               ,CONSTRAINED
              ) ON COLUMNS
            FROM 
            (
              SELECT 
                StrToSet
                (@BranchCountry
                 ,CONSTRAINED
                ) ON COLUMNS
              FROM 
              (
                SELECT 
                  StrToSet
                  (@PeriodPeriodWeek
                   ,CONSTRAINED
                  ) ON COLUMNS
                FROM 
                (
                  SELECT 
                    StrToSet
                    (@PeriodPeriodYear
                     ,CONSTRAINED
                    ) ON COLUMNS
                  FROM [DWH]
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
WHERE 
  (
    IIF
    (
      StrToSet(@PeriodPeriodYear,CONSTRAINED).Count = 1
     ,StrToSet
      (@PeriodPeriodYear
       ,CONSTRAINED
      )
     ,[Period].[Period Year].CurrentMember
    )
   ,IIF
    (
      StrToSet(@PeriodPeriodWeek,CONSTRAINED).Count = 1
     ,StrToSet
      (@PeriodPeriodWeek
       ,CONSTRAINED
      )
     ,[Period].[Period Week].CurrentMember
    )
   ,IIF
    (
      StrToSet(@BranchCountry,CONSTRAINED).Count = 1
     ,StrToSet
      (@BranchCountry
       ,CONSTRAINED
      )
     ,[Branch].[Country].CurrentMember
    )
   ,IIF
    (
      StrToSet(@BranchRegion,CONSTRAINED).Count = 1
     ,StrToSet
      (@BranchRegion
       ,CONSTRAINED
      )
     ,[Branch].[Region].CurrentMember
    )
   ,IIF
    (
      StrToSet(@BranchStoreCategory,CONSTRAINED).Count = 1
     ,StrToSet
      (@BranchStoreCategory
       ,CONSTRAINED
      )
     ,[Branch].[Store Category].CurrentMember
    )
   ,IIF
    (
      StrToSet(@BranchBranchName,CONSTRAINED).Count = 1
     ,StrToSet
      (@BranchBranchName
       ,CONSTRAINED
      )
     ,[Branch].[Branch Name].CurrentMember
    )
   ,IIF
    (
      StrToSet(@ItemGroupDescription,CONSTRAINED).Count = 1
     ,StrToSet
      (@ItemGroupDescription
       ,CONSTRAINED
      )
     ,[Item].[Group 1 Description].CurrentMember
    )
   ,IIF
    (
      StrToSet(@ItemGroupDescription2,CONSTRAINED).Count = 1
     ,StrToSet
      (@ItemGroupDescription2
       ,CONSTRAINED
      )
     ,[Item].[Group 2 Description].CurrentMember
    )
  )
CELL PROPERTIES 
  VALUE
 ,BACK_COLOR
 ,FORE_COLOR
 ,FORMATTED_VALUE
 ,FORMAT_STRING
 ,FONT_NAME
 ,FONT_SIZE
 ,FONT_FLAGS;
<Parameters xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
  <Parameter>
    <Name>PeriodPeriodYear</Name>
    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">[Period].[Period Year].&amp;[2014]</Value>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter>
    <Name>PeriodPeriodWeek</Name>
    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">[Period].[Period Week].&amp;[52]</Value>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter>
    <Name>BranchBranchName</Name>
    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">[Branch].[Branch Name].&amp;[Test Branch]</Value>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter>
    <Name>BranchCountry</Name>
    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">[Branch].[Country].[All]</Value>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter>
    <Name>BranchStoreCategory</Name>
    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">[Branch].[Store Category].&amp;[Test Cat]</Value>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter>
    <Name>BranchRegion</Name>
    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">[Branch].[Region].[All]</Value>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter>
    <Name>ItemGroupDescription</Name>
    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">[Item].[Group 1 Description].[All]</Value>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter>
    <Name>ItemGroupDescription2</Name>
    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">[Item].[Group 2 Description].[All]</Value>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter>
    <Name>ItemItemName</Name>
    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string"></Value>
  </Parameter>
</Parameters>
```

Here are the perfmon counters via MDX Studio:

```
Cold cache execution

Time              : 5 sec 125 ms
Calc covers       : 0
Cells calculated  : 24843
Sonar subcubes    : 7700
NON EMPTYs        : 3824
Autoexists        : 42
EXISTINGs         : 3824
SE queries        : 3833
Flat cache insert : 0
Cache hits        : 11513
Cache misses      : 11
Cache inserts     : 1
Cache lookups     : 11524
Memory Usage KB   : 98324

Warm cache execution

Time              : 41 sec 906 ms
Calc covers       : 0
Cells calculated  : 24843
Sonar subcubes    : 7698
NON EMPTYs        : 3824
Autoexists        : 42
EXISTINGs         : 3824
SE queries        : 3825
Flat cache insert : 0
Cache hits        : 11516
Cache misses      : 0
Cache inserts     : 0
Cache lookups     : 11516
Memory Usage KB   : -53232

Percent cold caches :0.00%
Percent warm caches :100.00%
```

**UPDATE2**

I also noticed the warm cache version spends a lot more time on NON EMPTY operation vs. cold cache version.

[image]

**UPDATE3**

SSAS process seems to use very little memory. The SSAS memory settings are default and the host has memory available.

[image]
[image]
[image]

**UPDATE4**

times with NON EMPTY removed from query

```
Cold cache execution

Time              : 23 sec 874 ms
Calc covers       : 0
Cells calculated  : 934213
Sonar subcubes    : 7711
NON EMPTYs        : 3822
Autoexists        : 45
EXISTINGs         : 3823
SE queries        : 3833
Flat cache insert : 0
Cache hits        : 11519
Cache misses      : 9
Cache inserts     : 3
Cache lookups     : 11528
Memory Usage KB   : 115700

Warm cache execution

Time              : 58 sec 905 ms
Calc covers       : 0
Cells calculated  : 934213
Sonar subcubes    : 7695
NON EMPTYs        : 3822
Autoexists        : 45
EXISTINGs         : 3823
SE queries        : 3825
Flat cache insert : 0
Cache hits        : 11518
Cache misses      : 0
Cache inserts     : 0
Cache lookups     : 11518
Memory Usage KB   : -54496

Percent cold caches :0.00%
Percent warm caches :100.00%
```

Comment: Can you share the query?

Comment: ...and trace from Profiler with all section 'Query Processing' events.

Comment: MY UNDERSTANDING--> http://www.ssas-info.com/forum/3-mdx-studio/1253-negative-memory-usage <-- As per this, *MDX Studio computes memory usage by taking snapshots of perfmon counter for memory before and after the query. If memory decreased - it will show negative number.*. Does it mean on executing the first query, somehow, the available memory has decreased, which leaves little memory to the subsequent runs?

Comment: @user448157 - Can you please run the same query, removing the `NON EMPTY` from the query and let us know the warm cache and cold cache times?

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti yes I have noticed a strange thing, not sure if it's normal. currently the SSAS process is only using around 130MB memory. Yet the memory settings are default and the machine has lots of memory resources available (see updated image in post)

Comment: Update qoestion with times

Comment: See this link --> http://www.entsoftsol.com/Home/Blog/memory-analysis-and-caching-in-ssas .

Comment: I am getting the feeling that folks at http://dba.stackexchange.com/ might be able to help you better! You should post the same question there as well